# Yet another teapot riddle (No.37)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

This riddle is probably very easy, I believe, but it's my first one (actually, it is my first riddle on the site).

The rules are as usual.

*I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings*

*Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)*

*Try to figure out the word with my hints.*

**1st hint**

> The first teapot is on the surface.
>   The second teapot always comes in a suit.

**2nd hint**

> The first teapot is usually female. 
>   The second teapot is usually male.

**3rd hint**

> The first teapot can be less than 4 or more than 6.
>   The second teapot usually goes up to 11.

Comment: First thought it was a Rot13(gvr) but it doesn’t fit all the clues except the second line in the first hint :\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this a

> Jack?

The first teapot is on the surface.

> Like a headphone jack?

The second teapot always comes in a suit.

> A playing card Jack

2nd hint
The first teapot is usually female.

> The female receptor end

The second teapot is usually male.

> The card jack is usually male

3rd hint
The first teapot can be less than 4 or more than 6.

> The size is either less than 4mm or greater than 6mm

The second teapot usually goes up to 11.

> A Jack’s value is usually 11 in cards, between the 10 and the Queen

Comment: Excellent answer! And ROT13(naq va Oynpx Wnpx, snpr pneqf ner jbegu gra, urapr **hc gb** ryrira)

Comment: Yes, it's right. You're excellent!