# Teapot Riddle no.38

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Thanks to [@trolley813](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21511/trolley813) for the cool [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73091/yet-another-teapot-riddle-no-37)

This Riddle has now 5 different words, which apply to that. If you have free time find more ... currently 4 words are found.

Rules as always:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
Try to figure out the word with my hints.

First hint:

> My first teapot fills stadiums
>   My second too

Second hint:

> My first teapot has rythm
>   My second teapot has no

Third hint:

> My first teapot can't hurt
>   My second teapot hurts someone

Final hint:

> My first teapot can make you feel different things
>   My second teapot can only make you feel pain

Good luck and have fun :)

Comment: The word i wanted to hear wasn't coming, only alternative solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess with

> beat as in sound beats and beating someone

My first teapot fills stadiums

> sound echoing through a stadium

My second too

> Thanks to @user477343: boxing matches held in a stadium.

My first teapot has rythm

> yea a sound beat has rhythm

My second teapot has no

> Not much rhythm in beating someone down

My first teapot can't hurt

> music doesn't hurt

My second teapot hurts someone

> beating someone will most likely hurt

My first teapot can make you feel different things

> Music can make you feel many things

My second teapot can only make you feel pain

> same as before beating down on a person will cause pain.

Comment: The second line might refer to (ROT13) obkvat zngpurf, creuncf. $(+1)$ :D

Comment: The first hint, second teapot : Rot(13) :Obkvat fcbegf, yvxr ZZN, Jerfgyvat svyyf fgnqvhzf

Comment: @Jannis knew it! :D

Comment: @user477343 what?

Comment: @Jannis In the line, "my second too", **mrdeadsven** did not have an explanation for it. I had a feeling that it might have been referring to your Rot13 comment :)

Comment: @user477343 Nc I'll include it in my answer with your name, I didn't think of it because when I think of stadiums I think of a dome like structure with an open roof (as in football matches) and I've never seen a boxing match in a stadium with open roof :p

Comment: Oh, thanks. I thought the same, but I sometimes watch WWE, so... :P

Comment: _By gawd he’s got a steel chair!!!_ Great answer! :D

Answer (score 7):

Is this

> ROCK?

My first teapot fill stadiums

> As in a rock band

My second too

> As in stones

Second hint:
My first teapot has rhythm

> Rock music has rhythm

My second teapot has no

> Stones do not

Third hint:
My first teapot can't hurt

> Rock music can’t hurt you

My second teapot hurts someone

> Stones can hurt people

Final hint:
My first teapot can make you feel different things

> Rock music makes different people feel different things

My second teapot can only make you feel pain

> Stones hurt when people throw them at you

Comment: This is almost my word :) Should I consider it as possible second solution?

Comment: @Jannis up to you, my friend! I’m happy with whatever you decide!

Comment: @Jannis if this is not the right solution, but can still pass nevertheless (and is just as good as the accepted answer, if it isn't this one), then I'll give this one a $50$ rep bounty :)

Comment: @user477343 Do what you want. My original solution isn't found yet.

Comment: @Jannis actually, thank you very much for making this particular teapot riddle! It has just given me an idea of another teapot! :D

Comment: @user477343 np. I'm having ideas of riddles too. Oh and this riddle was solved a minute ago

Comment: @Jannis just saw it :P

Answer (score 5):

My answer is inspired by and very similar to @El-Guest's answer - based on @Jannis' comment on it, I think the teapots are

> Metal

My first teapot fill stadiums

> Metal bands fill stadiums

My second too

> Metal constructions are used to build stadiums

My first teapot has rythm

> Metal music has rhythm

My second teapot has no

> Metal as a material does not

My first teapot can't hurt

> Metal music doesn't hurt

My second teapot hurts someone

> Various weapons are made of metal

My first teapot can make you feel different things

> Metal music can invoke different reactions from people

My second teapot can only make you feel pain

> Physical contact with metal can often hurt

Comment: @well we have a third solution ...

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a jab than a true guess (and you need some specific knowledge to get this one), but nonetheless, you are:

> Lions (the cat/[the team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_Lions))

First Hint:

> I'm thinking Roman times, lions in the Colosseum
> The team fills their stadium each week

Second Hint:

> Lionesses hunting involves coordination (or them being in rhythm)
> The team, especially in, say, [2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Detroit_Lions_season), was terrible!

Third Hint:

> I mean they can, obviously, in the wild but in a zoo (for example), you are safe from them
> Being a Lions fan has to be hurt

Final:

> Seeing a lion can be scary, exciting, inspiring, etc.
> Being a lifelong Lions fan has got to be painful (never won a Superbowl)!

Btw:

> Sorry Lion's fans :P

Comment: You got my vote up, before I even read the explanation :D, but it's really not what I meant. Though it's pretty good

Comment: Lol! I had no doubt it's wrong, but thanks!

Comment: The second one doesn’t “fill their stadium” ;p but as a Pats fan this is _too soon_.

Answer (score 2):

The fourth and fifth possible answer:
Inspired by @Taki and @EL-Guest

> Electro

and

> Trap: a stadium is normally not full of traps, only at a trap convention. So it's the fifth answer

Comment: Could you care to explain how Electro relates to the line: My second too. Cause I'm guessing it refers to the genre electro and electricity? But I fail to see how electricity fills a stadium :p.

Comment: @mrdeadsven well where's the light and the monitors coming from, and how can music be played in a stadium? :D did you try the 1st solution?

Comment: Ohh ok I'm dumb for some reason I was thinking of lightning in its pure form, so I was thinking like are you going to strike a stadium with a lightning bolt 0.o

Comment: @mrdeadsven np . Everyones brain doesn't want from time to time. Any though of the first possible solution?