# Teapot Riddle no.39

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
Try to figure out the word with my hints.

First hint:

> My first teapot controls
>   My second teapot controls too
>   My third teapot controls nothing

Second hint:

> My first teapot can be written,or can be fluent
>   My second teapot must be written
>   My third teapot should be written

Third hint:

> My first teapot is in any Language
>   My second teapot is in some languages
>   My third teapot is in any combination of it's languages

Final hint:

> My first teapot is enforced by the chief
>  My second teapot is enforced by a machine
>  My third teapot can't be enforced

Good luck and have fun :)
[last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73097/teapot-riddle-no-38)

Comment: In the second hint, are two of them related to the "second teapot" on purpose? Also, in third one : "is any Language" is complete or is there a "in" missing?

Comment: @Marvin  sh!t, thanks for telling me, i'll correct asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puzzled me the whole week end... as a computer scientist, I feel this is related to computer science.

So another cs-related proposal :

> "**code**" : code (of conduct), a computer language, and a chiffre

My first teapot controls

> Rules lead us!

My second teapot controls too

> The software is controlled by its code

My third teapot controls nothing

> A chiffre can't control a thing

My first teapot can be written,or can be fluent

> Rules can be written down, or can be told, like how to eat right or where to put the fork (left or right)

My second teapot must be written

> Computer code must be written!

My third teapot should be written

> Trying to encrypt something, you really should write it down. You can't do that in mind

My first teapot is in any Language

> There are rules in every language

My second teapot is in some languages

> Computer langugaes only!

My third teapot is in any combination of it's languages

> You can encode sth, and then encode it again and again

My first teapot is enforced by the chief

> Mostly...

My second teapot is enforced by a machine

> Indeed

My third teapot can't be enforced

> Chiffre can't be enforced, why should it?

Comment: Rot 13  V zrnag pbqr (bs pbaqhpg) / pbqr (bs n cebtenzz) / naq pbqr (puvsser)

Comment: Thats not quite what i thought, even though its the right word

Comment: Damned, I ruined the thing with my poor guess!!

Comment: thats ok, just change a bit

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Command

My first teapot controls

> **command** - an authoritative order

My second teapot controls too

> **command** - an instruction or signal causing a computer to perform one of its basic functions

My third teapot controls nothing

> **command** - the ability to use or control something

My first teapot can be written,or can be fluent

> Commands may either be written down or spoken.

My second teapot must be written

> Computer commands are written to a terminal

My third teapot should be written

> Demonstration of a command of a subject should be written to be demonstrated.

My first teapot is in any Language

> Authoritative commands are given in any language

My second teapot is in some languages

> Programming languages

My third teapot is in any combination of it's languages

> They have a good *command* of English/French/Spanish/etc

My first teapot is enforced by the chief

> An authority figure

My second teapot is enforced by a machine

> The machine into which the commands are typed

My third teapot can't be enforced

> Nobody can be forced to gain expertise on a subject.

Comment: Not what i had in mind, but nice :) +1 from me. AND!: the second teapot is right

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about ...

> "go" : a spoken /written order (go!), a computer language (go), and a game (go)

My first teapot controls

> go go go!

My second teapot controls too

> Computer

My third teapot controls nothing

> ... as far as I know, at least...

My first teapot can be written,or can be fluent

> It's basicely an order that can be written or spoken

My second teapot must be written

> Computer language!

My third teapot should be written

> ... the main flaw in my reasoning here : maybe stg should be written about it?

My first teapot is in any Language

> As far as I know, everyone understands the go! order

My second teapot is in some languages

> Computer science ones only!

My third teapot is in any combination of it's languages

> No need of any language to speak, thus any people regardless of their language can play!

My first teapot is enforced by the chief

> Indeed

My second teapot is enforced by a machine

> Indeed

My third teapot can't be enforced

> Indeed :)

Comment: I'm sorry it's not the word I'm searching for, but cool you're on it again :)

Answer (score 2):

Another try...

I was thinking about ...

> "order" : the given by your wif.. chief!, the one you need to buy spare parts on internet, and the order of things (A,b,c, etc.)

My first teapot controls

> I order you to build an ark!

My second teapot controls too

> Controls stocks... mainly

My third teapot controls nothing

> This is a state

My first teapot can be written,or can be fluent

> can be written or spoken

My second teapot must be written

> you have to write it before sending it

My third teapot should be written

> to keep track of it!

My first teapot is in any Language

> All languages have ways to give an order

My second teapot is in some languages

> Not all languages allow to place orders

My third teapot is in any combination of it's languages

> You can order whatever you wanna sort, including words from various languages

My first teapot is enforced by the chief

> Indeed

My second teapot is enforced by a machine

> Hmmm... not always (now it's sure, I am wrong again...)

My third teapot can't be enforced

> Hmmm.... it can be.

Ok, I am surely wrong, but I have to try one last time, anyway!

Comment: It's as you said wrong, but nice try :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about..

> **Rules**

My first teapot controls

My first teapot can be written,or can be fluent

My first teapot is in any Language

My first teapot is enforced by the chief

> As in, ground rules. It controls the way you should behave, it can be written in a rulebook or be told verbally. These kind of rules can be defined in any language and are usually enforced by a chief in a work environment.

My second teapot controls too

My second teapot must be written

My second teapot is in some languages

My second teapot is enforced by a machine

> These are coding rules, coding conventions. These rules control the way you write your computer code. They must be written down for them to work when used with StyleCop for example, which checks your coding style and corrects you. So that's being enforced by the machine. The only languages where these can be enforced in are programming languages.

My third teapot controls nothing

My third teapot should be written

My third teapot is in any combination of it's languages

My third teapot can't be enforced

> Something like "school rules!", it's being used as a verb here. It doesn't control anything that way. It definitely should be written on a wall with some nice graffiti art to go with it. It could be written in various languages, and the police can't seem to enforce graffiti since it's still happening everywhere. Also, you can't enforce someone's opinion. Not sure about this one though, haha.

Comment: It's not the word,  but the first teapot is right. Good job :) Oh and hello to my riddles, I haven't seen you here until now

Comment: *Welcome  - instead of hello

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

> Instruction

As in

> Instructions (orders) a person says to anyone else, code instructions and instructions manuals and guides.

Explanations in a minute.

Comment: Thats not the word i meant

Comment: Oh. Just to discard: what about rot13(znahny)? (it doesn't quite match the second teapot, though)

Comment: @Rasco Yep that's not the word either

Answer (score 0):

Might it be

> Script first as in movie script, second as in computer script like javascript and third script UNICODE?

Comment: I'm sorry it's not. But nice try :)