# Teapot Riddle no.40

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Already so many... i need to make myself thoughts about specials.
BTW: this is some kind of special since this word has 7 teapots

Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
Try to figure out the word with my hints.

*Have fun*

First Hint:

> My first teapot is Mr.Reacher
>   My second teapot is plastic
>   My third teapot is paper
>   My fourth teapot is metal
>   My fifth teapot is a job
>   My sixth teapot is an act
>   I won't tell you about the seventh teapot -x-

Second Hint:

> My first teapot is Mr.Ryan
>   My second teapot is for safety
>   My third teapot is for fun
>   My fourth teapot is for assistance
>   My fifth teapot is for boots
>   My sixth teapot is for enrichment
>   I definetly won't say a thing

Final Hint:

> The son of my first teapot is Michael
>  My second teapot is a lock
>  My third teapot is the win
>  My fourth teapot is a lift
>  My fifth teapot is a clean
>  My sixth teapot is stealing
>  Stop reading about the seventh teapot

Good luck and have fun :)
[last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73101/teapot-riddle-no-39)

Comment: I was just in the middle of making a $40$th. $41$ it is, then! :D

Comment: @user477343 linked?

Comment: Yup. I just posted it :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer must be

> Jack

My first teapot is Mr.Reacher

> **Jack** - male first name, e.g, Jack Reacher (movie)

My second teapot is plastic

> **Jack** - a socket with two or more pairs of terminals designed to receive a jack plug.

My third teapot is paper

> **Jack** - a playing card bearing a representation of a soldier, page, or knave

My fourth teapot is metal

> **Jack** - a device for lifting heavy objects

My fifth teapot is a job

> Boot **jack**.

My sixth teapot is an act

> **Jack** - take (something) illicitly; steal.

I won't tell you about the seventh teapot -x-

> **Jack** - synonymous with nothing, e.g, "I ain't saying Jack!"

My first teapot is Mr.Ryan

> Jack Ryan - new TV series by Amazon

My second teapot is for safety

> Designed to hold the jack plug in place

My third teapot is for fun

> Playing cards

My fourth teapot is for assistance

> For leveraging a car to change a tire

My fifth teapot is for boots

> A boot jack is used to remove boots.

My sixth teapot is for enrichment

> Enriching the criminal

I definetly won't say a thing

> Still saying Jack

The son of my first teapot is Michael

> Michael **Jack**son

My second teapot is a lock

> A jack socket could be considered a weak type of lock

My third teapot is the win

> Black**jack** - what you need to win the game.

My fourth teapot is a lift

> Elevates the vehicle in question

My fifth teapot is a clean

> Boot jacks also clean the boot?

My sixth teapot is stealing

> By definition

Stop reading about the seventh teapot

> You won't get Jack from me.

Comment: Thats Right, did you solve with or without Final Hint?

Comment: Yes, although I'm not sure about the second or fifth teapots.

Comment: I meant  with the second Rot 13(fbpxrg naq gur svsgu vf obbgwnpx), seems this riddle could have at least 9 teapots. ADs : reacher is a movie as well as Ryan a series AND I'm so sorry I meant a different **** as seventh teapot what goes with ****

Comment: And there is another teapot the lumber****