# Teapot Riddle no.41 (fan made)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

**Teapot Riddle no.41 (fan made).** 
 *Welcome*.

> > **Rules:**
>
> *I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
>
> Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...).
>
> You try to figure out the word with my Hints.*

- **First Hint:**

  > My first teapot's sweet, and my second will fill. 
  >  They each have a seat, but one might face downhill.
- **Second Hint:**

  > My first is surrounded by neighbours, or not. 
  >  My second is crowded with all tickets bought.
- **Third Hint:**

  > My first might have you eat then sleep for the night. 
  >  My second can, too, if the show won't excite.
- **Final Hint (to make it easy):**

  > My first, you must own, or of that you'll be less. 
  >  My second, alone, won't see queues (or success). 
  >  
  >  My third's on a tower that spread from a bean. 
  >  My fourth will have power, up (red) or down (green).

Good luck and have fun!
[Last teapot riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73145/teapot-riddle-no-40?noredirect=1&lq=1). Big thanks to @[Jannis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52327/jannis) for making them!

Comment: xD That was a quick upvote :P **Edit:** Just realised that (ROT13) Gur ynfg fragrapr va gur svany uvag fbhaqf yvxr vg vf qrfpevovat n genssvp yvtug. Gur nafjre vf sne sebz gung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is

> Home. First as in your home, Second as in a home game (with regards to sports)

My first teapot's sweet, and my second will fill. 
They each have a seat, but one might face downhill.

> Home sweet home. A home game will fill. They both have seats but a home game may be in a stadium with seats going down hills

My first is surrounded by neighbours, or not.

> Your home is next to neighbours.

My second is crowded with all tickets bought.

> Will get crowded, people buy tickets to a home game.

My first might have you eat then sleep for the night.

> You eat and sleep in your own home

My second can, too, if the show won't excite.

> If the game is a bit boring you might get sleepy?

My first, you must own, or of that you'll be less.

> You either have a home or you are homeless.

My second, alone, won't see queues (or success).

> If the home team is on their own, then people won't turn up and they won't beat anyone.

My third's on a tower that spread from a bean.

> Jack and the Beanstalk reference. The giants have a home at the top of the stalk.

My fourth will have power, up (red) or down (green).

> Fuse boxes in homes will have a green LED when the power is down (indicating that it is safe to do electrical work) and a red switch when up.

Comment: This is not it, but it fits $100\%$ and it is the closest answer, so I am probably going to award this a $50$ rep bounty. If nobody answers this riddle correctly after I do that, then I will just accept this answer. This is a beautiful alternative! Well done! :D

Comment: Well, congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ $\boxed{\color{blue}{+50}}$

Comment: Here was the intended answer, such that the teapot should be clear in the following Rot13: 1fg = ubhfr (be ubzr, nf va ubzr fjrrg ubzr); 2aq = ubhfr (nf va, ubhfr nhqvrapr); 3eq = ubhfr (nf va, gerrubhfr); naq 4gu = ubhfr (nf va, ubhfrf bs cneyvnzrag; v.r., terra/hccre ubhfr (ercerfragngvirf) naq erq/ybjre ubhfr (frangr)).

Comment: ROT13: V npghnyyl unq ubhfr vavgvnyyl ohg unq lbhe 4gu qrsvavgvba nf gur 2aq bar naq pbhyqa'g svther vg bhg. V'z abg snzvyvne jvgu gur grez "ubhfr nhqvrapr" gubhtu, naq tbbtyr qbrfa'g ghea hc nalguvat. Jung qbrf vg zrna?

Comment: ROT13: Nabgure grez sbe "gurnger" vf "cynlubhfr". Gurer ner cnegf bs n gurnger gung ner ersreerq gb nf OBU (onpx bs ubhfr) naq SBU (sebag bs ubhfr). V unir jbexrq jvgu zhygvcyr gurnger pbzcnavrf gung nyfb ersre gb gur nhqvrapr nf gur "ubhfr". Guvf vf fbyryl sebz crefbany rkcrevrapr :Q

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

> Yard?(backyard/stadium i.e. [Camden Yards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriole_Park_at_Camden_Yards))

First Hint:

> Time spent with friends/family can produce sweet memories
> Stadiums get filled with fans (not Camden, currently though)
> Yard chairs and stadium seats. Stadium seats face downhill to see the field

Second Hint:

> The yard probably has neighbors on each side, unless you live next to a road, or have a lot of property
> Fans buy tickets to watch the game

Third Hint:

> I'm thinking having a cookout then going to bed (maybe camping)
> Games, especially baseball, can be boring, putting you to sleep

Final Hint:

> Home owning can be seen as superior to renting or being homeless?
> The field doesn't really contribute to success, the team on the field does
> Third - not sure
> Fourth - also, not sure :-\

Comment: That is not the answer, but 'tis a real good effort! I am glad that I added the Rot13(guveq naq sbhegu) in the final hint, because otherwise this would have been an alternative! I'm probably going to spoil the answer by saying the following hint, but oh well, you are quite close. (ROT13) Bar bs zl grncbgf unf lbhe nafjre :D (and I have to wait 12 hours before I can upvote again; DVL12).

Comment: @user477343 yeah, I didn't think so.  I was surprised that ROT13(gur havg bs zrnfherzrag) wasn't included

Comment: Yeah, it would have been, I suppose, if this was the answer. Again, 'twas a very nice try, nonetheless! :) Oh, and one last thing: the title is a clue if you didn't think... and one of the teapots can be found in your answer, even though it isn't your answer :P

Comment: As a Blue Jays fan, this resonates with me...we’re bad, but thank goodness we’re not _Oriole bad_ (this year...jinxed it)

Comment: @El-Guest as an Orioles fan, I'm used to it lol

Comment: @El-Guest what's this, baseball? Grab me a hot dog! :D

Comment: @Greg I’m so sorry for everything, friend

Comment: @El-Guest Thanks, but I'm sure you aren't sorry for 2016 :P

Comment: @Greg I’m so sorry for everything that happened this year, now that we’re basement buddies again

Comment: @El-Guest lol!!

Answer (score 1):

Made me think of

> Cordial a sincere friendly person or cordial the drink

My first teapot's sweet, and my second will fill. 
They each have a seat, but one might face downhill.

> first cordial a sweet person, second the drink will fill you up. No idea for the last sentence.

My first is surrounded by neighbours, or not.

> cordial persons mostly have a lot of people around them, but not always.

My second is crowded with all tickets bought.

> They probably sell the drink at some events.

My first might have you eat then sleep for the night.

> not sure maybe cordial people want to make sure everyone is OK for the day.

My second can, too, if the show won't excite.

> referring to the previous you drink something with your food and before you go sleep (maybe unintended pun my second CAN :p)

My first, you must own, or of that you'll be less.

> being cordial isn't for everyone and if your not friendly against other you might be seen as less because other might not like you.

My second, alone, won't see queues (or success).

> not sure maybe when they are in the shop their are many and people are in queues to buy them once you bought it they are alone. also if no one wants to buy it (no queues) the drink won't have success.

My third's on a tower that spread from a bean.

> no idea

My fourth will have power, up (red) or down (green).

> cordial is also to cheer, give strength and spirit. no idea for the up and down part.

Comment: No, that is not the answer, unfortunately. @Greg 's answer was closer (and actually got one part correct, but for the wrong reasons). This was a good attempt.  The "filling" up part is a different kind of fill, but I like the pun! "Puns of fun" (ohhh... that was terrible) xD 'Twas a good attempt, though. The title is a clue :)