# Teapot Riddle No. 42 (Fanmade)

Tags: riddle, word

*So, I thought I'd like to give it a shot at making one of these.. Here goes:*

> > **RULES :**
>
> I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings
>
> Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
>
> Try to figure out the word with my hints.
>
> > **HINT 1 :**
>
> My first teapot will hurt you physically
>
> The second one will hurt you mentally
>
> > **HINT 2**
>
> The third teapot mixes it up on the dance floor
>
> The fourth will mix it up in the kitchen
>
> > **HINT 3**
>
> The fifth teapot tells you to leave
>
> The sixth one expresses disbelief

Have fun everyone

And [here's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73151/teapot-riddle-no-41-fan-made?noredirect=1&lq=1) the last one of these.

Comment: Lol you have the same format as mine :D

Comment: yah, sorta did follow the format.

Comment: Well, that's kinda cool :D

Comment: This riddle is number "life, the universe, and everything". It would have been cool if the fact the riddle is number 42 had to tie in with the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I got it:

> Beat

Hint 1

> Beat physically

Hint 2

> Beaten (lost a game)

Hint 3

> Beat (a song played by a DJ that incites dancing)

Hint 4

> Egg beater

Hint 5

> "Beat it!"

Hint 6

> "Beats me..."

Comment: maybe for the sixth teapot, it could be a slang expression? e.g. (ROT13) "V'z orng" be "lbh orng zr" :)

Comment: good start, the last two needs correction though.

Comment: @Chuckey has gotten the last two correct, you can add them to your answer.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid Added.

Comment: now it's correct, will accept tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 5 :

> beat it (get out of here)

Hint 6 :

> beats me? (how did He get the job?)

Comment: good job, these are correct.