# Teapot Riddle no.43

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot Riddle no.43
Rules
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
Try to figure out the word with my hints.

*today less hints than usual*
First Hint:

> My first teapot is elemental to survive
>   My second teapot isn't elemental to survive
>   My third teapot helps to survive
>   My fourth teapot helps the third teapot

Second and last Hint:

> My first teapot is a basic market principle
>   My second teapot is a basic presentation principle
>   My third teapot is a general principle
>   My fourth teapot comes from the principal

Good luck and have fun :)
[last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73198/teapot-riddle-no-42-fanmade)
and probz to [Shahriar Mahmud Sajid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37211/shahriar-mahmud-sajid) for making it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are:

> ORDER

My first teapot is elemental to survive / is a basic market principle

> To place an order as you would order food. You can't survive without food. Likewise ordering stock is essential for any kind of sales or marketing.

My second teapot isn't elemental to survive / is a basic presentation principle

> You would present things *in order* but this is not necessarily essential to survival.

My third teapot helps to survive / is a general principle

> The *state* of order (as opposed to chaos) helps survival.

My fourth teapot helps the third teapot / comes from the principal

> A *command* from an authority (such as a school principal) helps create a state of order.

Comment: Rot 13 : Beqre: va n erfgnhenag,bs fgu, beqre nf fgngr vgfrys (rirelguvat va beqre),naq beqre nf pbzznaq (beqre 66)

Comment: please correct this post

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are

> INTEREST

although some of these meanings seem uncomfortably close to one another and some of the hints don't fit as well as I'd like.

First teapot refers to

> what matters to a person or institution, as in phrases like "in your best interest" or "self-interested". It's "elemental to survive" because remaining alive is perhaps the most fundamental interest any living thing has, and because a person or animal that didn't pursue its own interests would die. It's "a basic market principle" because, to an excellent approximation commonly used in economics, participants in a market are simply seeking their own interests.

Second teapot refers to

> being interested in things. It's "not elemental to survive" because "curiosity killed the cat", or perhaps just because you can survive just fine if you're bored. It's "a basic presentation principle" because if you're giving a presentation, the most important thing is to keep the audience interested in what you say.

Third teapot refers to

> having a financial stake in something; e.g., if you hold shares in a company you can be said to have an "interest" in it. It "helps to survive" in the same way as any asset does. It is "a general principle" because, er, um, I'm not sure. (Perhaps the first and third meanings need to be switched?)

Fourth teapot refers to

> interest on loans. It "helps the third teapot" because, well, again I'm not quite sure, but many businesses benefit from e.g. issuing bonds. (Here again switching first and third would help, but other things would suffer.) It "comes from the principal" in the sense that being paid interest on a loan is a consequence of loaning out the principal.

Comment: thats not the word i'm looking for

Comment: Ah well, never mind. It was worth a go.

Answer (score 2):

Is your teapot

> HAND?

My first teapot is elemental to survive

> This might refer to the Invisible Hand

My second teapot isn't elemental to survive

> Using HANDS to point or gesture

My third teapot helps to survive

> You need HANDS to survive

My fourth teapot helps the third teapot

> Hey, give them a HAND!

Second and last Hint:
My first teapot is a basic market principle

> The Invisible Hand is an economic principle postulated by Adam Smith

My second teapot is a basic presentation principle

> Gesturing with hands is encouraged in presentations

My third teapot is a general principle

> Generally everyone needs hands

My fourth teapot comes from the principal

> Who can give you a hand

Comment: it's not, sorrry. Nice try though

Comment: Also, what is the difference between the second and third teapot?

Comment: @hexomino In some context second and third are same, but the third is more general

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

> Savings

You can explain it as

> 1. Saving stocks/money for future usage. 
>  
>  2. It is like saving your presentation on the computer.
>  
>  3. Like saving food or material.
>  
>  4. Your savings come from the money that you have or the principal amount.

Comment: It's not but nice try :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> Discipline

My first teapot is elemental to survive
My first teapot is a basic market principle

> self-control or self-restraint (discipline) is important both to survive as well as in the market.

My second teapot isn't elemental to survive
My second teapot is a basic presentation principle

> An orderly pattern of behavior (discipline) isn't elemental to survive, but it is a good presentation principle to be orderly.

My third teapot helps to survive
My third teapot is a general principle

> A subject that is taught (or a discipline) helps survive and is a general principle

My fourth teapot helps the third teapot
My fourth teapot comes from the principal

> This can be the discipline handed down from teachers/principles to enforce good learning environments

Comment: almost but not the word I'm referring to, nice try :)