# Teapot Riddle no.44

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot riddle no.40:

Rules
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
Try to figure out the word with my hints.

First Hint:

> My first teapot is a group of people using my second teapot
>   My second teapot is a system using my third teapot
>   My third teapot is using force

Second Hint:

> My first teapot shouldn't be dirty
>   My second teapot is partly dirty
>   My third teapot can be dirty in sports

Third Hint:

> My first teapot reproduces everything
>   My second teapot reproduces data
>   My third teapot doesn't reproduce

Good luck and have fun :)
[last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73286/teapot-riddle-no-43)

Comment: So there is a group of people that can reproduce *everything*? I am waiting for the solution in order to align the way of my life accordingly.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis yeah, but in an abstract way. Sry I can't describe further

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another try again... with the help of JGibbers!

May it be...

> .. **press**? The press (a group of journalists), the press (printing machine), the press (urgency)

My first teapot is a group of people using my second teapot

> untill here, it matches

My second teapot is a system using my third teapot

> they are always under pressure because news must remain ... news :)

My third teapot is using force

> Hmm.... first flaw, or I don't know how to formulate such as it eventually matches

My first teapot can be from clean to dirty

> Unfortunately!

My second teapot can be dirty

> Most of the time, it is inky!

My third teapot can be dirty in sports

> Sounds right, though I am not sure one does say it that way...

My first teapot reproduces everything

> They do...

My second teapot reproduces data

> It does....

My third teapot doesn't reproduce

> Not in a way I understand...

Comment: ahhhh, I like this!

Comment: I'm sry I saw this so late ... This answer is right and to the last one: I meant (to) third teapot

Comment: @Jannis Could you then explain the way it "uses force"? I'm still puzzled about this (this may be obvious for a native English speaking, but I am not :p )

Comment: rot13 (vs lbh jnag gb cerff n ohggba, lbh arrq sbepr. h hfr sbepr)

Answer (score 5):

Alright coming in with a guess:

> Copy ?

My first teapot is a group of people using my second teapot

> Copy writers will use a...

My second teapot is a system using my third teapot

> Copy machine (or copier) is a system that copies (not quite using the third teapot)

My third teapot is using force

> Carbon copy is a way of engraving things to multiple pages with pressure (or force

My first teapot shouldn't be dirty

> Clean copy is a copy w/o any markups

My second teapot is partly dirty

> Copy editing is editing copy with markups or notes (partly dirty)

My third teapot can be dirty in sports

> Copying playcalls or signs is viewed as dirty in a lot sports

My first teapot reproduces everything

> this one i'm not too sure about (or at least how to differentiate with the second clue in this hint)

My second teapot reproduces data

> Copy/paste

My third teapot doesn't reproduce

> Copyrights prevent you from reproducing data

Comment: you're almost right. First Hint, second teapot is right ;)

Answer (score 2):

First thing that came to my mind was

> Command as in Command center, computer commands and a Command

My first teapot is a group of people using my second teapot

> a command center uses computer commands

My second teapot is a system using my third teapot

> Computer commands uses commands to program

My third teapot is using force

> holding command over something is utilizing your force

My first teapot can be from clean to dirty

> No idea

My second teapot can be dirty

> dirty programming e.g. a lot of loops etc.

My third teapot can be dirty in sports

> holding command over someone in sports can be considered playing dirty

My first teapot reproduces everything

> when a command comes in they all reproduce (copy) the command to forward it

My second teapot reproduces data

> computer command generate data

Comment: It's not the word, but nice guess. Maybe I do " ******* " in another riddle. And dirty programming  is 'goto' for example

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... may it be...

> .. **board**? A board (of executive), a (black)board, a board (the piece of wood)

My first teapot is a group of people using my second teapot

> a board of executive in front of a white/black board

My second teapot is a system using my third teapot

> a board is made of a frame and a board, mainly

My third teapot is using force

> Note sure how it does match here... maybe when used as a diving board?

My first teapot can be from clean to dirty

> I don't know about their clothes, but their practice may be dirty!

My second teapot can be dirty

> Until it is cleaned

My third teapot can be dirty in sports

> A board used as a tool (snowboard, diving board, etc.)

My first teapot reproduces everything

> Managment!

My second teapot reproduces data

> If it does not reproduce only data, it matches... otherwise, I am surely wrong!

My third teapot doesn't reproduce

> Not in this reality

Comment: This is not the word I'm searchingt for, but its a nice try. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think the common word is:

> Copy

And the three teapots are:

> 1. People or teams who make copies of things, such as photocopies.
>  2. Machines that copy (like a photocopier)
>  3. The process of copying.

**First Hint:**

My first teapot is a group of people using my second teapot

> People who work in copy use photocopiers

My second teapot is a system using my third teapot

> A photocopier uses the process of copying.

My third teapot is using force

> The process of copying is an *action* and so force is used.

**Second Hint:**

My first teapot shouldn't be dirty

> People who do copying shouldn't be dirty! I wouldn't take my copying to them if they were.

My second teapot is partly dirty

> Photocopier machines can get dirty. That toner can get everywhere.

My third teapot can be dirty in sports

> To copy someone in certain kinds of game could be "dirty" or cheating.

**Third Hint:**

My first teapot reproduces everything

> Give something to a copy team and they will reproduce it all for you.

My second teapot reproduces data

> A copy machine digitises the image into data and then reproduces it.

My third teapot doesn't reproduce

> The process of copying on a computer (as in copy & paste) doesn't actually reproduce anything - but the *paste* action does.

Comment: How is this different from the answer given by JGibbers?

Comment: @feelinferrety Because the aim of the teapot riddle is to explain the three different meanings of the word. The author has told JGibbers that his reasoning is incorrect, and if you read it he has just used the same meaning of the word in different contexts. I have outlined three different things that can be called by the same term.