# Teapot Riddle no.45

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

*I really don't know what to write here ...*
Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
Try to figure out the word with my hints.

*Toast bread*

First Hint:

> My first teapot should use my second teapot
>   My second teapot shouldn't be my first teapot, when you
>   do my third teapot against the wall

Second Hint:

> My first teapot is a human
>   My second teapot is a part of my first teapot
>   My third teapot is a move all humans do

*Go, Human

Use my third teapot

It's a critical hit

:D XD*

Third Hint:

> My first teapot can gain money and fame
>   My second can gain Voltage
>   My third can gain speed

Good luck and have fun :)
[last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73288/teapot-riddle-no-44)

Comment: Your puzzles are good, but I really think you should stop using things like wtf and sh!t. It's not just about censoring them, but the quality of language that has been used on this forum has been really good so far and I think that should be maintained. Allowing small things like these to creep in is what eventually leads to a bad environment. Please consider removing or replacing such terms in your posts.

Comment: considered :D ...

Comment: @nikki I agree - it isn't about censorship or being prudish. By keeping it clean this is a great site for all ages. As well as that, bad language just cheapens a puzzle - especially riddles, which are supposed to be about clever use of language.

Comment: @Astralbee I also agree; for example, [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73289/the-thirteen-doors-of-aj-nocla) is absolutely brilliant. No bad language can be found and it even has a clever riddle; I ignore that kind of language anyway, but it still does "cheapen a puzzle" as you put it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer may be...

> **head** (leader), **head** (the upper boy part of her/him), **head** (a move)

*Toast bread*

> ... because you can hear "(h)ead"?

**First Hint:**

> My first teapot should use my second teapot
>  Indeed!

'

> My second teapot shouldn't be my first teapot, when you
>  do my third teapot against the wall : 
>  
>  the head (body part) heading against a wall should not belong to a leader!

**Second Hint:**

> My first teapot is a human
>  Not always... but that fits mainly :)

'

> My second teapot is a part of my first teapot
>  As long as it not choped down!

'

> My third teapot is a move all humans do
>  it's basicley a "move ahead"? (not sure it's correct english)

*Go, Human

Use my third teapot

It's a critical hit

:D XD*

> another part I cannot match...

**Third Hint:**

> My first teapot can gain money and fame
>  Indeed!

'

> My second can gain Voltage
>  This part puzzles me... maybe when sentenced to death?

'

> My third can gain speed
>  Sounds reasonnable for a move

Comment: Toast bread refenreces to my very first sentence. don't know what to write. Go human ... references to Pokemon and the bad description i used for all riddles... Poor jokes of myself are confusing. and gaining voltage is in a biological sence of second teapot thinking ability

Comment: and the **** shouldn't lead as first part of the body when running against a wall

Comment: ... indeed : I didn't read it the correct way... now it's obvious!!